# I am getting a white screen on my android emulator upon compilation using react-native navigation. I do not seem to get any Error codes

Tags: react-native

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import HomeScreen from './components/Homepage'
import ProfileScreen from './components/Profilepage'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default MyStack
```

components/Homepage/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {View , Button, Text} from 'react-native'

const Homepage = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Homepage</Text>
      <Button onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Profilepage')} title='Next Screen'></Button>
    </View>
  )
};
export default Homepage
```

components/Profilepage/index.js

```
import React from "react"
import {View, Button, Text} from 'react-native'

const Profilepage = () => {
  return (
    <Text>Hello</Text>
  )
};

export default Profilepage
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "carpool2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

[image: white android screen & terminal running]

I expected a "Homepage" text and a button to appear in the beginning, and for a "Hello" text to appear on the next screen when clicking on the Homepage button (navigating to a new screen). The screen refreshes after saving any changes but remains white.

Comment: can you share your package.json file. ithink you are mmssign some depenency

Comment: I've uploaded my package.json file above, not sure what to look for

Comment: install reac-native-gesuter-handler package

Answer (score 0):

Please try giving style `flex: 1` in View.

components/Homepage/index.js

```
const Homepage = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>Homepage</Text>
      <Button onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Profilepage')} title='Next Screen'></Button>
    </View>
  )
};
```

components/Profilepage/index.js

```
const Profilepage = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  )
};
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. The screen remains white